# how to check in mysql which serialize array is contain value that i want to find

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I store many arrays in mysql  using php serialize function.

but problem is that,
How can i find any one value that conatain serialize arrays.

i am very confuse how to get that array , that contain my value.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="get" action="test1.php">
<input type="text" name="first_singer"/><br>
<input type="text" name="second_singer"/><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$singer1=$_GET['first_singer'];
$singer2=$_GET['second_singer'];

$singer=array($singer1,$singer2);

$array=serialize( $singer );

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2") or die();;
$array=serialize($singer);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ('$array')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 echo 'query susseful';
 }
}
?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The better way is to save the data into a normalied database instead of serializing the values. As you see now there will be a huge effort reading the values from serialized data.

Comment: i don't know about normalization .so give me the best way

Comment: What was the outcome of your own research regarding to normalization?

Answer (score 0):

First of all maybe you have to thing to change your approach.

Instead of storing serialized arrays you should think to create a proper table schema for your data. If you really need to store this kind of data structure probably you have to think of using some kind of NoSQL database like MongoDB where you can store that kind of structure as JSON.

But it's possible to access to your data but it's quite dirty. You can try to match your item using MySQL Like.

For instance, you have an array with an email and products that belongs to that name, you can do something like:

select * from your table where serialized_item like '%my@email.com%';

And then you can unserialize that array and process that item.

But as I said, that's not a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=serialize( $singer );

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2") or die();;
$array=serialize($singer);
```

Replace these lines to

```
$array=serialize( $singer );

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test2") or die();;
```

After select values from table use `unserialize()` method.